# server for fetching a url and passing the results back

Tags: java, node.js, web-services, http

I want to build a server that when invoked, it simply fetches the url that you pass it and sends the result back

I'm pretty sure there are many of these projects on guthub but I don't know what to search. I tried 'proxy server' but the results are not what im looking for

eg : `myserver.com?/fetch?url=reddit.com` fetches reddit.com and returns the result

Comment: It's not clear for me why do you use `java` and `node.js` tags together in your question? What technology do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Easy do it with [express](http://expressjs.com/) and [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package

```
var app = require('express')(),
    request = require('request');

function addHttp(url) {
    if (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?\:\/\//.test(url))
        return "http://" + url;
    return url;
}

app.get('/fetch', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.url);
    request.get(addHttp(req.query.url)).pipe(res)
});

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else  console.log('magic start at port 3000')
})
```

Then try

```
localhost.com:3000/fetch?url=reddit.com
```